# Remove blank row from grid

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, dynamically-generated

i try to add records dynamically in grid

```
Private Sub AddToGrid()
    If ViewState("table") IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim dtable As DataTable = DirectCast(ViewState("table"), DataTable)
        Dim drow As DataRow = Nothing

            For i As Integer = 0 To dtable.Rows.Count
                drow = dtable.NewRow()
                drow("ID") = TEXT_1.Text
                drow("Name") = ddl_name.SelectedItem.Text
                drow("Type") = ddl_type.SelectedItem.Text
            Next
            dtable.Rows.Add( drow)
            ViewState("table") =dtable
            gridv.DataSource = dtable
            gridv.DataBind()
        End If

End Sub

Private Sub AddDefaultFirstRecord()  
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Dim dr As DataRow
    dt.TableName = "table"
    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("ID"))
    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Name"))
    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Type"))
    dr = dt.NewRow()
    dt.Rows.Add(dr)
    ViewState("table") = dt
    gridv.DataSource = dt
    gridv.DataBind()
End Sub

Protected Sub Add_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Add.Click
    AddToGrid()
End Sub
```

and on page load i call this

```
AddDefaultFirstRecord()
```

when i add record then grid has empty blank row so how i remove this row

like this

```
       ID       Name     Type
Delete               
Delete  92615   Din     tYPE1
```

So how to remove this empty blank row i am not adding this when i click on add then with record this empty row i added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove following code from `AddDefaultFirstRecord()`:

```
dr = dt.NewRow()
dt.Rows.Add(dr)
```